# LaTeX Error: File `pdftexcmds.sty' not found

Tags: pdftex, packages

I can't compile using Rmarkdown anymore. Everytime I try to knit a PDF on Markdown it says:

```
"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS Rapport-de-stage.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output Rapport-de-stage.tex --self-contained --table-of-contents --toc-depth 4 --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --lua-filter "C:/Users/famic/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:/Users/famic/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/latex-div.lua" --include-in-header "C:\Users\famic\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCmECzQ\rmarkdown-str176c2d407187.html" --variable "geometry:margin=1in" 
tlmgr.pl: package repository http://ctan.tetaneutral.net/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr.pl install: package already present: pdftexcmds
! LaTeX Error: File `pdftexcmds.sty' not found.

! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

Error : LaTeX failed to compile Rapport-de-stage.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Rapport-de-stage.log for more info.
```

I try to uninstall R and RStudio but it doesn't work.

Comment: which tex system are you using?

Comment: I'm using Tinytex

Comment: pdftexcmds.sty was moved from tex/latex to tex/generic, and probably your tex system didn't really catch up. Check if you can find pdftexcmds.sty. And do whatever maintenance tasks you know (`tlmgr update --self --all` , mktexlsr, etc).

Comment: I can't find pdftexcmds.sty... I'm a beginner so I don't know about tlmgr update

Comment: Nevermind, I typed mktexlsr on the terminal and it works just fine now ! Thank you so much !

Comment: Well I'm a complete beginner in R, I have no idea what you are doing when you "knit a pdf in Markdown" ;-).

Comment: There might also be another issue at play here. Isn't also tinytex a thing in R, a setup for tex but not tex itself. Have had students with issues @UlrikeFischer

Comment: @daleif tinytex is based on texlive only smaller. A missing mktexlsr after an update looks like a probablle cause of the error. But I don't know if it or R has some special search setups. If you know more cases you should perhaps open an issue at the tinytex github to ask.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I know, but there is also an R package of the same name, very confusingly

Comment: I had the same issue for weeks, since June I believe. It worked before June. I ran the following code from https://yihui.org/tinytex/ (essentially reinstalling it) ```
install.packages('tinytex')
tinytex::install_tinytex()
``` It must have been an update issue or they fixed it!